# Create certificate from a csr, crt and rsa file

Tags: iis, openssl, certificate, csr, crt

The certificate provide me with the files mentioned above but I don't remember how to create a certificate file to install on iis, I remember using the openssl tool

Comment: Contact whoever sent you those files to learn what they exactly are. There are some references like https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43697/what-are-the-differences-between-pem-csr-key-crt-and-other-such-file-exte but file extensions can be misleading if the sender decided to use a different one. Once you know which ones are the private key and certificate, you can use OpenSSL to merge them as a PFX file for IIS.

Comment: You can refer to [this blog](https://zeropointdevelopment.com/how-to-get-https-working-in-windows-10-localhost-dev-environment/) about creating certificate and import to local machine. Then you can see it in IIS certificate module.